# reading from a text file in C Programming

Tags: c

I am trying to write a C program that is able to read data (strings) from a text file and swap each content in terms of bytes. I have already implemented the code and everything works just fine, and and I am able to read all the contents of the specified text file, but the problem is that the program is printing the last word from the text file twice and I do not know why? Any help will be helpful ! This is the code I have:

```
while( !feof(ptr_file))
{
    //to read in group of words (sentences) if
    //needed !.
    fscanf(ptr_file, "%s", userName);   
    //time to swap letters of the word coming from the text file.
    swap_a_word(userName, 0, 4);
    swap_a_word(userName, 1, 2);
    //new space.
    printf("\n");
    //display the word after swapping to the screen for the user.   
    printf("%s", userName);
}
```

The program must not print extra data. I do not know, but when the program reaches the end of the file, it prints the last data of the text file twice. Please any hints will be helpful !.

Thanks !

Comment: Your use of `feof()` is wrong. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `while` loop condition

```
while(!feof(ptr_file))
```

Note that `EOF` is preceded by a newline `'\n'`. `fscanf` returns the value `EOF` when the end of file is reached. However, this does not set the end-of-file indicator on the stream and as a result the loop is entered one extra time. You should check the return value of `fscanf` instead to find number of items successfully matched and assigned.